# First seven columns are unexpectedly empty in 'svn status -v' output

Tags: svn, command-line, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to get unversioned items by using 'svn status -v' in command line (Windows, TortoiseSVN) and expect to have something like this (got from 'svn help status'):

```
  svn status --show-updates --verbose wc
   M           965       938 kfogel       wc/bar.c
         *     965       922 sussman      wc/foo.c
  A  +           -       687 joe          wc/qax.c
               965       687 joe          wc/zig.c
  Status against revision:   981
```

First seven columns are supposed to be flags, but I get them empty like this:

```
  svn status --show-updates --verbose wc
               965       938 kfogel       wc/bar.c
               965       922 sussman      wc/foo.c
                 -       687 joe          wc/qax.c
               965       687 joe          wc/zig.c
  Status against revision:   981
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD1:** It seems that I have some forced ignore-list in my svn, and that's why I can't see some unversioned folders. Namely I need to delete ReleaseUnicode and DebugUnicode folders which are somehow ignored.

**UPD2, RIGHT ANSWER:** yes, the answer was in folder properties, some of my folders have 'svn:ignore' property (found it in repo-browser) which prevented from showing them as 'unversioned'.
The confusing part was that UI option 'Delete unversioned files' doesn't pay any respect to this 'svn:ignore' property and shows content without any ignore-signs.

Comment: Show us the real command you issue and the screenshot of it's output. Looks like you are missing something.

Answer (score 0):

[Unversioned items are always marked with `?`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine.status). You don't need to run `svn status` with `--verbose` argument to get unversioned items.